# strange behavior orbiting around an orbiting object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am attempting to make obj1 orbit around obj0, and similarly make obj2 orbit around obj1 like so:
(something like sun, earth, moon but on one plane)

```c#
using UnityEngine;

public class orbitMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform pivot;

    void Update()
    {
        if(pivot!=null){
            transform.RotateAround(pivot.position, Vector3.up, Time.deltaTime * 77);
        }
    }
}
```

obj1 orbits fine around obj0, but when i'm adding obj2 to orbit obj1, it shoots away from obj1, and starts orbiting it in ever growing radius. 
what am i missing?

Comment: Could you add the complete code? Are the objects nested in the scene hierachy or independent GameObjects? Remember that child objects are moved along if you move the parent object ;)

Comment: @derHugo sure, i put the whole code, but there is not much addition...
the objects are independent, not parenting- i set the reference manually at the inspector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why it works for the first but not for the second is the following:

I assume obj0 is static and doesn't move in your scene -> rotating around it with a constant offset is no problem.

**But** `obj1` moves. So when `obj2` gets to call `RotateAround` in this frame the pivot `obj1` has already moved so the offset is every frame slightly bigger resulting in a growing offset to the pivot.

---

Personally I would rather use a structure like e.g.

```c#
earthPivot
|-earth
moonPivot
|-moon
```

then you can set the pivot to the according position and let it rotate around itself. The according child is automatically rotated along but keeping a constant offset to the parent. You could then still add a local rotation for the child objects themselves for a) overwrite the parents rotation and b) add a rotation itself.

```c#
public class PivotRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform pivot;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    private void Update()
    {
        transform.position = pivot.position;
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
    }
}
```

And on the child

```c#
public class ChildRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotationSpeed;
    private Quaternion rotation;
    private void Update()
    {
        rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0,Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed, 0);
        transform.rotation = rotation;
    }
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*